# Destructor and Constructor calls, Example right?

Tags: c++, constructor

I had to polish up my understanding of the circumstances under which constructors are called. During this I stumbled over [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#nrvo_cpp05_topic3) from Microsoft:

```
//RVO class is defined above in figure 4
#include <stdio.h>
RVO MyMethod (int i)
{
            RVO rvo;
            rvo.mem_var = i;
            throw "I am throwing an exception!";
            return (rvo);
}
int main()
{
            RVO rvo;
            try 
            {
                        rvo=MyMethod(5);
            }
            catch (char* str)
            {
                        printf ("I caught the exception\n");
            }
}
```

The `RVO` class simply has constructor, copyconsdtuctor and destructor print when they are called. Microsoft states that with thorw commented out and no NRVO the output will be:

```
I am in constructor
I am in constructor
I am in copy constructor
I am in destructor
I am in destructor
I am in destructor
```

However I can't quite follow. I think that this is what happens:

1. In main `constructor` is called for `RVO rvo;`
2. In MyMethod `constructor` is called for `RVO rvo;`
3. For `return (rvo);` the `copyconstructor` is called
4. In MyMethod `destructor` is called for the local RVO
5. In Main `destructor` is called for the local rvo

This leaves me with one less `destructor` call than microsoft proclaims. What am i missing?

For completness the `RVO` class:

```
class RVO
{
public:

            RVO(){printf("I am in constructor\n");}
            RVO (const RVO& c_RVO) {printf ("I am in copy constructor\n");}
            ~RVO(){printf ("I am in destructor\n");}
            int mem_var;       
};
```

Comment: If you have three constructors, three destructors will be eventually called, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look carefully at the statement rvo=MyMethod(5);

rvo is assigned by the return object of MyMethod, the return object should be constructed in the scope of the main function. This object is unnamed and is a temporary object. the constructor of such an object is shown in the output that is not obvious on first look.

Comment: exactly what I missed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't be confused. Without return-value optimization, *three*) objects are created (*including* the temporary used for copying via copy constructor), and therefore *three* objects are being destroyed (including the temporary once again), so it's all good.

With RVO though, the temporary will not be created while copying (the object will be created in the caller's stack frame directly), and you will see only two constructions and two destructions.

Answer (score 0):

rvo is constructed in main()

rvo is constructed in MyMethod

a unnamed RVO-object is copy-constructed from the rvo in MyMethod by the return statement

all three objects are destroyed

Answer (score 0):

"In main constructor is called for RVO rvo; In MyMethod constructor is called for RVO rvo; For return (rvo); the copyconstructor"
So three objects are constructed, in normal circumstances there should be three destroyed. The returned value also needs to be destructed.